# Cookie check doesn't work

Tags: php, html, cookies

I'm making a cookie system, but It doesn't work; I have this code:

```
<?php
$cookie = $_GET['cookie'];

if(empty($cookie))
{
    $cookie = '';
}

if($cookie = 'ok') 
{  
    setcookie("terminos", "", time() + 60*60*24*365*10);
}
elseif($cookie = 'no')
{
    ?>
    <div id="pmyr_div">
        <center style="position: relative; top: 50%; margin-top: -23px;margin:auto 0;">
            <img src="cooltext1105916314.png" style="margin-top:20px;" />
            <br><br>
            <big><b>USTED TIENE EL ACCESO DENEGADO A ESTE SITIO POR DENEGAR NUESTROS TÉRMINOS LEGALES.</b></big>
            <br><br>
            <a href="index.php?state=test"><b>De acuerdo, seré un chico bueno.</b></a>
        </center>
    </div>
    <?
}
elseif($cookie = 'test')
{
    setcookie("user", "", time()-60*60*24*365*10);
    header('location: index.php?cookie=raw');
}
elseif($cookie = 'raw')
{
    ?>
    <div id="pmyr_div">
        <center>
            <br><b>MUY IMPORTANTE!<br>ES NECESARIO QUE SE LEA NUESTROS TÉRMINOS LEGALES.</b><br><br>Sólo puede entrar en este sitio web <b>si es mayor de 18 años de edad</b>, o al menos la mayoría de edad en la jurisdicción donde usted reside o del que se accede a esta página web.<br><br>Si usted no cumple con estos requisitos, entonces usted NO ESTÁ AUTORIZADO, Y NO DEBE INGRESAR a este sitio web.
            <br><br><br><br>
            <a href="index.php?cookie=ok" style="color: #8e1a1a;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;">SOY MAYOR DE 18 AÑOS</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="index.php?cookie=no" style="color: #8e1a1a;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;">NO ENTRAR</a>
        </center>
    </div>
    <?
}
elseif(empty($cookie))
{
    ?>
    <div id="pmyr_div">
        <center>
            <br><b>MUY IMPORTANTE!<br>ES NECESARIO QUE SE LEA NUESTROS TÉRMINOS LEGALES.</b><br><br>Sólo puede entrar en este sitio web <b>si es mayor de 18 años de edad</b>, o al menos la mayoría de edad en la jurisdicción donde usted reside o del que se accede a esta página web.<br><br>Si usted no cumple con estos requisitos, entonces usted NO ESTÁ AUTORIZADO, Y NO DEBE INGRESAR a este sitio web.
            <br><br><br><br>
            <a href="index.php?cookie=ok" style="color: #8e1a1a;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;">SOY MAYOR DE 18 AÑOS</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="index.php?cookie=no" style="color: #8e1a1a;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;">NO ENTRAR</a>
        </center>
    </div>
    <?
}

if(isset($_COOKIE["terminos"]))
{
    //page content here
}
elseif(!isset($_COOKIE["terminos"]))
{
    ?>
    <div id="pmyr_div">
        <center>
            <br><b>MUY IMPORTANTE!<br>ES NECESARIO QUE SE LEA NUESTROS TÉRMINOS LEGALES.</b><br><br>Sólo puede entrar en este sitio web <b>si es mayor de 18 años de edad</b>, o al menos la mayoría de edad en la jurisdicción donde usted reside o del que se accede a esta página web.<br><br>Si usted no cumple con estos requisitos, entonces usted NO ESTÁ AUTORIZADO, Y NO DEBE INGRESAR a este sitio web.
            <br><br><br><br>
            <a href="index.php?cookie=ok" style="color: #8e1a1a;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;">SOY MAYOR DE 18 AÑOS</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="index.php?cookie=no" style="color: #8e1a1a;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;">NO ENTRAR</a>
        </center>
    </div>
    <?
}
?>
```

When I press the link `SOY MAYOR DE 18 AÑOS` the message doesn't disappear. I think that the cookie isn't set.

What can I do?

Comment: I don't speak Spanish, so I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Are you expecting to read `$_COOKIE["terminos"]` in the same script where you set it?

Comment: Yes... I can't do this? Or what?

Comment: if($cookie = 'ok')  something's wrong here.

Comment: `$_COOKIE` contains the cookies that were received **from** the client, `setcookie()` sets the cookies that will be sent **to** the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting an empty cookie

```
setcookie("terminos", "/*here you have to put a value*/", time() + 60*60*24*365*10);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: It's work, I set a name, but as you can see here. Doesn't work. :(
http://mastermusik.bugs3.com/

Comment: It is not required, but always the if(empty($cookie)) return true,no es requerida pero entonces el if(empty($cookie)) siempre retorna verdadero porque la cookie no tiene valor

Comment: Jajaja! Eres español, menos mal... Okey.. It works for you? See my page por favor. xD

Comment: He never uses the value of the cookie, just whether the cookie is set or not. `$cookie` doesn't contain the cookie value, it contains the value of a URL parameter named `cookie`.

Comment: What you are trying to do is restrict the access to the person that age is less than 18 years?

Comment: Well, not exactly I will edit some text, and change "SOY MAYOR DE 18 AÑOS" by "I AGREE THE TERMS" or something like that, I have another problem, the cookies aren't set every time I reload the page you can see that the message are showed... :(

Comment: @Barmar i saw that at this moment, but the other problem is he doesnt set cookies

Comment: when you set the cookie like i show you in the answer with a value, you can get the value later as follow $_COOKIE["terminos"] http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

Comment: But the name aren't terminos? I'm cheking terminos, I have to check other name?

Comment: If I put the name that I have put (on the second value) It doesn't work. :(

Comment: A ver.. XD se supone que para comprobar si la galleta xD no.. xD la cookie está puesta, tengo que comprobarla con $_COOKIE["terminos"] no? Es que me has liado, se supone que el segundo campo del setcookie es solo para comprobarla luego con un if... no?

Comment: Se supone que tu guardes algun valor en la cookie para hacer algun tipo de comparacion con if despues, poder condicionar algun comportamiento en tu sitio

Comment: Ahhh vale. xD Voy aprobar algo... Y te cuento. (Por cierto, estará permitido hablar en español por aquí? xD)

Comment: Si pongo: $_COOKIE['terminos'] === "nombre de la cookie" valdrá?

Comment: remember $_COOKIE is an associative array, "terminos" is a key of the array , i dont know if spanish is allowed, also is a free country...lol ....http://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.cookies.php is in spanish

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33048/discussion-between-emilio-gort-and-ikillnukes)

Answer (score 2):

In all your `if` and `elseif` statements, you have something like:

```
($cookie = "ok")
```

It should be:

```
($cookie == "ok")
```

`=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparing.

For using the cookie, put the following at the top of the script:

```
$cookie_is_set = isset($_COOKIE['terminos']);
```

After each of your `setcookie()` calls, add:

```
$cookie_is_set = true;
```

Then at the bottom of the script, instead of

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['terminos']))
```

use:

```
if ($cookie_is_set)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now the page load well... But the cookies for some reason aren't set... :(

Comment: Like I said in my comment above, you can't try to read `$_COOKIE` in the same PHP process that set the cookie. That only contains the cookies that were received when the script started.

Comment: What can I do? Can I try a require_once('index.php'); or what can I try?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Why do you think you're doing something bad?

Comment: Because when you press the link and you refresh, the message shows again as you can see on my web. :( PD: You have to delete this part of the link /index.php?cookie=ok